# changing quicksight [spice] data field type of CSV(from s3) imported using boto3

Tags: boto3, amazon-quicksight

I am trying to change the field type, it says only string is allowed for S3 how to change that?

```
response = client.update_data_set(
    AwsAccountId='AwsAccountId',
    DataSetId='DataSetId',
    Name='Name',
    PhysicalTableMap={
        'string': {
            'S3Source': {
                    'DataSourceArn': 'arn:aws:quicksight:us-east-1:AwsAccountId:datasource/DataSourceId',
                    'UploadSettings': {
                        'Format': 'CSV',
                        'StartFromRow': 1,
                        'ContainsHeader': True,
                        'Delimiter': ','
                    },
                    'InputColumns': [
                        {
                            'Name': 'col1',
                            'Type': 'DATETIME'
                        },
                        {
                            'Name': 'col2',
                            'Type': 'STRING'
                        },
                        {
                            'Name': 'col3',
                            'Type': 'DECIMAL'
                        },
                        {
                            'Name': 'col5',
                            'Type': 'STRING'
                        },
                        {
                            'Name': 'col6',
                            'Type': 'DECIMAL'
                        }
                    ]
                }
        }
    },
    ImportMode='SPICE')
```

and this is the error it shows

```
InvalidParameterValueException: An error occurred (InvalidParameterValueException) when calling the CreateDataSet operation: Input column col1 in physical table string has invalid type. Allowed types for S3 physical table are [String]
```

how can I create a table using csv from s3 and have data type other than string? Please help....
Thanks in Advance